# Error when using Select() instead of Include() in a query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have the following query:

```
var catInclude = _db.Cat
    .Where(x => x.ProvId == request.ProvId)
    .Include(x => x.CatItems)
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == request.ProvId
         cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

As I don't want to get all properties from CatItems with Include(), I have created the following query:

```
var catSelect = _db.Cat
.Where(x => x.ProvId == request.ProvId)
.Select(p ==> new
    { Provider = p,
      Items = p.CatItems.Select(x => new List<CatItems> { new CatItems
{ Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, Price = x.Price } }
})})
SingleOrDefault(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

But something is wrong in the 2nd query because here `return _mapper.ProjectTo<CatDto>(cat)` I get the following error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from '<anonymous type: Db.Entities.Cat Prov, System.Colletions.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Colletions.Generic.List<Models.CatItems> > Items>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Here is my `CatDto`:

```
public class CatDto
{
   public int ProvId { get; set; }
   public List<CatItems> CatItems { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my entities:

```
public class Prov
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Cat Cat { get; set; }
}

public class Cat
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int ProvId { get; set; }
   public List<CatItems> CatItems { get; set; }
}

public class CatItems
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int CatId { get; set; }
   public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to recreate the 2nd query and use it?

Comment: Please don't tag EF and EFCore; theyre differnet products. Decide which you're using and also tag the version

Comment: `Items = p.CatItems.Select(x => new List<CatItems> { new CatItems { ... } })` seems very suspicious. Every item in the source list gets wrapped in a single-element `List<T>`, which is then added to a parent `IEnumerable<T>`. Are you sure you didn't mean: `Items = p.CatItems.Select(x => new CatItems { ... }).ToList()` instead?

Comment: If you project to `CatDto` and a new `CatItemDto` by `ProjectTo` EF will already only pick the fields you need. There's no need for `Include` or the other preparation you tried. Some answers explain the error, but if you simply do `_db.Cat.Where(x => x.ProvId == request.ProvId).ProjectTo<CatDto>().SingleOrDefault()` all your problems are gone and you need none of the answers.

Comment: @GertArnold if I make those changes I can’t find a valid argument for `.ProjectTo<CatDto>()`.

Comment: @Homeboy53 you didn't provide a feedback for my answer. Did you miss it?

Answer (score 1):

Main difference that instead of returning `List` of `CatItems`, your code returns `IEnumerable<List<CatItems>>` for property `Items`.

So, just correct your query to project to `List`:

```cs
var catSelect = await _db.Cat
    .Where(x => x.ProvId == request.ProvId)
    .Select(p => new CatDto
    { 
        ProvId = p.ProvId,
        Items = p.CatItems.Select(x => new CatItems
        { 
            Id = x.Id, 
            Name = x.Name, 
            Price = x.Price 
        })
        .ToList()
    })
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Comment: I have tried the above query but I get the following error: > cannot convert from ‘anonymous type: Db.Entities.Cat Prov, System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.CatItems> > Items>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Comment: Corrected, just copied from your original message.

Comment: The issue with the above query is that it includes all the CatItems properties. I get values for Id, Name and Price but I also get CreatedOn with a default date. Is there a way to exclude CreatedOn property on this query?

Comment: Actually we excluded all what we can. If EF Core generates SQL which contains these  properties - it is a bug.

Comment: I think something is wrong in my CatDto. So, if I’m running this Select in a GET, I get all properties from List<CatItems> - including CreatedOn which should not be included. Probably because I use the property List<CatItems> in CatDto is the reason that I get all the properties in my GET? How can I choose only the properties that I want - Id, Name and Price from this list to be displayed on GET?

Comment: I'm looking at this from LINQ translation perspective. I know how it works and sometimes take a look at EF Core source code. And what I saw it is possible bug. And no, DTO configuration has almost zero influence. Which EF Core version do you use?

Comment: All I want is to display the list of CatItems of a specific Prov in a GET, without the property CreatedOn. I have EF Core 6.

Comment: I have noticed that if I use [JsonIgnore] on CreatedOn property it’s excluded from the GET. But I dont’t think it’s an elegant solution. I’m open to other solutions.

Comment: No solutions, it is a bug in EF Core with Eager Load.

Comment: Do you use AsSplitQuery? EF Core has two modes how to do Eager Load.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, even the exception is pretty self-explanatory. Nevertheless:

You are performing a `.Select(...)`. It returns an *Anonymous* type. So, your `catSelect` is an anonymous type, thus the `AutoMapper` fails.

The quickest fix is to just cast `(Cat)catSelect` before mapping.
Or, you can dig deeper into how does AutoMapper play with anonymous types.

Comment: I tried to cast before mapping but it doesn’t let me. I need to change this Select in a way to work, so digging deeper in Automapper is not an option here.

Answer (score -1):

I feel like you can make most of the classes inherent Id and why is public cat CAT {get; set;} i thought you were supposed to initialize some kind of value

Comment: What is this related to the question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).